# Envío de mensajes incompletos usando xbee y mysql

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa en `python` que me permite enviar datos de una base de datos en `mysql` mediante un `xbee` a otro `xbee`.

Actualmente tengo 27 registros en la base de datos, lo datos se envían correctamente hacia el otro `xbee` pero solo se envían 10 o 9 datos de los 27 que tengo en la base de datos.

Solo una vez se enviaron los 27 y después de esto solo se envían los primeros 9 o 10 datos de la base de datos.

¿Alguien sabe porque me pasa esto?

Este es mi código:

```
import time
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
import mysql.connector

sql_conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='pass', 
host='localhost', database='XBee')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
device = XBeeDevice('COM3', 9600)
device.open()

while True:
    try:
        dataSQL = []
        cursor.execute("SELECT estation,colour FROM xbeesend")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            station = row[0]
            colour = row[1]
            m = station + ";" + colour + " "
            print("Sending: " + m)
            device.send_data_broadcast(m)
        time.sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

sql_conn.close()
device.close()
```

Saludos.

Comment: ¿El  `print("Sending: " + m)` si te imprime las 27 veces o tampoco?

Comment: Tampoco, solo me imprime los primeros 9 datos.

Comment: ¿Que te muestra `print(len(rows))`?

Comment: Me muestra el numero 27.